# How can I access nested objects that are not similiar and iterate through them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, websocket

I have a connection to a websocket that gives me data in this format.

`{lastUpdateId: 2303,Bids: [[ '12312.81000000', '0.77085400' ],[ '23423.79000000', '0.02179700' ],[ '23423.76000000', '0.00550000' ],[ '23422.70000000', '0.00052800' ],[ '64536.24000000', '0.00902500' ]],}`

I want to put all the primary value of "bids" arrays in a new xBids array and secondary value of "bids" arrays in a new yBids array.
so it looks like this.

`xBids = ['12312.81000000','23423.79000000','23423.76000000','23422.70000000''64536.24000000'] yBids = ['0.77085400','0.02179700','0.00550000','0.00052800''0.00902500']`

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `xBids = result.Bids.map(b => b[0]);` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function `.map()` to return a new array that contains values that are derived from an existing array.

```js
const result = {lastUpdateId: 2303,Bids: [[ '12312.81000000', '0.77085400' ],[ '23423.79000000', '0.02179700' ],[ '23423.76000000', '0.00550000' ],[ '23422.70000000', '0.00052800' ],[ '64536.24000000', '0.00902500' ]]}

const xbids = result.Bids.map(bid=>bid[0]);
const ybids = result.Bids.map(bid=>bid[1]);

console.log('xbids: ', xbids);
console.log('ybids: ', ybids);
```

Comment: Thanks very elegant and simple solution. I was going around it wrong the whole way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#map`.

```js
const obj = {lastUpdateId: 2303,Bids: [[ '12312.81000000', '0.77085400' ],[ '23423.79000000', '0.02179700' ],[ '23423.76000000', '0.00550000' ],[ '23422.70000000', '0.00052800' ],[ '64536.24000000', '0.00902500' ]],} 
const arr1 = obj.Bids.map(x => x[0]), arr2 = obj.Bids.map(x => x[1]);
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

To do it with only one traversal of the array, you can use `Array#reduce`.

```js
const obj = {lastUpdateId: 2303,Bids: [[ '12312.81000000', '0.77085400' ],[ '23423.79000000', '0.02179700' ],[ '23423.76000000', '0.00550000' ],[ '23422.70000000', '0.00052800' ],[ '64536.24000000', '0.00902500' ]],};
const [arr1, arr2] = obj.Bids.reduce((acc,[x,y])=>(acc[0].push(x), acc[1].push(y), acc), [[], []]);
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

this works (ES6 syntax):

```
const testObj = {lastUpdateId: 2303,Bids: [[ '12312.81000000', '0.77085400' ],[ '23423.79000000', '0.02179700' ],[ '23423.76000000', '0.00550000' ],[ '23422.70000000', '0.00052800' ],[ '64536.24000000', '0.00902500' ]],};
const xBids = [];
const yBids = [];
testObj.Bids.map(bid => { xBids.push(bid[0]), yBids.push(bid[1])});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple but requires two iterations.

```
let xBids = response.Bids.map(element=>{
  element[0];
}
)

let yBids = response.Bids.map(element=>{
element[1];
})
```

Single iteration method

```
let xBids= [];
let yBids = [];
response.Bids.forEach((element)=>{
xbids.push(element[0]);
yBids.push(element[1])
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ***map()*** function to create the 2 new arrays which contain the required data as shown below.

```js
const data = {
  lastUpdateId: 2303,
  Bids: [
    ['12312.81000000', '0.77085400'],
    ['23423.79000000', '0.02179700'],
    ['23423.76000000', '0.00550000'],
    ['23422.70000000', '0.00052800'],
    ['64536.24000000', '0.00902500']
  ]
};

const xBids = data.Bids.map(bid => bid[0]);
const yBids = data.Bids.map(bid => bid[1]);

console.log(xBids);
console.log(yBids);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this task in 1 operation as well using reduce:

Idea:

- Create a nested array structure.
- Loop on Bids and on every iteration, push current value to necessary array.
- Return this nested structure for next iteration as well.
- At completion, receive this structure are separate it.

```js
const data={lastUpdateId: 2303,Bids: [[ '12312.81000000', '0.77085400' ],[ '23423.79000000', '0.02179700' ],[ '23423.76000000', '0.00550000' ],[ '23422.70000000', '0.00052800' ],[ '64536.24000000', '0.00902500' ]],} 

const [xBids, yBids] = data.Bids.reduce(([xBidsList, yBidsList], [x, y]) => [
    [...xBidsList, x],
    [...yBidsList, y]
  ],
  [[], []]
)

console.log(xBids, yBids)
```

Simplified version for clarity:

```js
const data={lastUpdateId: 2303,Bids: [[ '12312.81000000', '0.77085400' ],[ '23423.79000000', '0.02179700' ],[ '23423.76000000', '0.00550000' ],[ '23422.70000000', '0.00052800' ],[ '64536.24000000', '0.00902500' ]],} 

const xBids = [];
const yBids = [];

data.Bids.reduce((bidLists, bid) => {
  const xValues = bidLists[0]
  const yValues = bidLists[1]
  
  xValues.push(bid[0])
  yValues.push(bid[1])
  
  return [xValues, yValues]
}, [ xBids, yBids ])

console.log(xBids, yBids)
```